# Why can't I use if [operator] == true: in python?

Tags: python

For example, I want to check whether a number in a list is either 1,2 or 3:

```
def function(a):
    list=[1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        if item not a == True:
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

If I try `function([2,4])` for example, it won't print anything. I have to assign item not in a to a variable like so:

```
def function(a):
    list=[1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        x=item in a
        if x == True:
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

Why doesn't python allow this? Can I shorten my code somehow

Comment: You are iterating over the list, and checking for equality between each of the items and the list that contains the items ? That will never work.

Comment: You never check your input against your list.

Comment: That is a super complicated way to simply say `return a in [1,2,3]`

Comment: Doesn't naming a `list`, `list` will potentially hide the actually type or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `item` is in a list by simply stating `if item in list:`.

```
def function(a):
    list=[1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        if item in list:
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the comparison with `True`!

```py
def function(a):
    list = [1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        if item in list:
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

Also, checking membership will be O(1) with a set, instead of a list where it is O(n), so if you may have long / different lists, you can use `{}` instead of `[]`:

```py
def function(a):
    list = {1,2,3}
    for item in a:
        if item in list:
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a typo: you're looking for the `in` rather than the `not` operator.

```py
def function(a):
    list=[1,2,3]
    for item in a:
        if item in list: # Change 'not' to 'in'
            print('Number is either 1,2 or 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to write this succinctly is:

```
def function(a):
    list_ = [1, 2, 3]
    return any(x in list_ for x in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things not correct with your code.

First, you are iterating over the list, and checking for equality between each of the items and the list that contains the items - that will never work.

Then, you are checking if `comparison_statement == True` which just produces another `True` or `False` - you can just delete that.

Also, you should not overwrite the builtin `list` with a variable.

Here is a working version:

```py
def function(a):
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    for item in a:
        if item in l:
            print('Number is either 1, 2 or 3')
```

If you want it to be short, use `any` with a generator expression:

```py
def function(a):
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    return any([i in l for i in a])

if function([2, 4]):
    print("Number is either 1, 2 or 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a number in some list is also in some other list:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
some_other_list = [4,8,1]

for item in some_other_list:
    if item in my_list:
        print("Number is either 1,2 or 3")
        print(f"The number is {item}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with your statement, what about this (it worked for me):

```
def function(a):
    for item in a:
        if item not in list:
            print("number is neither 1,2,or 3")
        else: print("ok")
```

That means your statement should be `if item not in list:` instead of the one you are using now.